# How to create an edifact file in data waever component of mule

Tags: mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio, edifact

I am receiving an xml file and my requirement is to create an edifact
file from that xml. But in the dataweaver component of mule, there is
not support for edifact file formats. So is there a way I can generate
an edifact in mule from dataweaver or any other component.

Comment: did you able to find any useful sample for the beginners. please share

Comment: not yet.@ jerith2: Whats your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generate valid edi documents then you should use edifact-module in mule. It looks complicated but once you start it its really easy. You just need to understand EDI Schema Language (ESL) which is a predefined structure in Mule. You can use DataWeave with output type as application/java. Then pass this output to EDI Connector and it should be able to output EDI document.

I recently used X12 EDI connectors and was able to get it working once I understood ESL. Mule documents https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-b2b/edifact-module should be the good place to start.

Comment: Thanks I will try. But if have any problem or doubts will again land here for clarification.

Comment: @ManikMagar how to generate ESL schema from edi file ?

Comment: @jerith2 if you are using standard definitions of messages then you don't need to generate ESL. They are included in module jar, you can refer them into connector. If you want to override any ESL then only you would extend the default ESL and write you own. Check - https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-b2b/edi-schema-language-reference

Comment: @jerith2 why you want to generate ESL?

Comment: @ManikMagar: Can you tell me how to insert new line in edifact file after each segment

Comment: Do you have a sample you are trying to generate? That might help me to suggest solution.

Answer (score 0):

this component suits your needs ?
https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-b2b/edifact-module

Comment: This document is not exactly what I am looking for. May be not very clear for the beginners like me. I am more interested in how i extract data from my input xml and place those data in .edi file. The documentation is not clearly indicating anything on that

Comment: @David Dossot  Have got any suggestions